# How can I port a relational database to Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am playing around with Neo4j but trying to get my head around the graph concepts. As a learning process I want to port a small Postgres relational database schema to Neo4j. Is there any way I can port it and issues "equivalent" relational queries to Neo4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tool does exactly that.
Import any relational db into neo4j
https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-rdbms-import

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid not. The relational data model and the graph data model are two different ways of modelling a real-world domain. It requires a human brain (at least as of 2013) to understand the domain in order to model it.

I suggest that you take a piece of paper and capture, using circles and arrows, what your entities are (nodes) and how they relate to each other (relationships). Then, have a look at that piece of paper. Voila, your new Neo4j data model.

Then, take a query that you want to be answered and try to figure out how you would do that without a computer, just by tracing your nodes and relationships with a finger on that piece of paper. Once you've figured that out, translate what you've done to a Cypher query.

Have a look at neo4j.org, there are plenty of examples.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can port your existing schema to a graph database. Keep in mind that this is not necessarily the best model for your data, but it is a starting point.

How easy it is depends a lot on the quality of your existing schema.

The tables corresponding to entities in an entity-relationship-diagram define your types of nodes. In the upcoming neo4j 2.0, you can labels them with the name of the entity to make a lookup easier. In older versions you can use an index or a manual label property.

Assuming a best case, where all your relationships between data is modelled using foreign keys, any 1:1 relationship between nodes can be identified and ported next.

For tables modelling n:m relationships, identify the corresponding nodes and add a direct relationship between them.

So as an example assume tables `Author[id, name, publisher foreign key]`, `Publisher[id, name]` and `Book[id, title]` and `written_by[author foreign key, book foreign key]`.

- Every row in `Author`, `Publisher` and `Book` becomes a node.
- Every `Author` node gets a relationship to the publisher identified by the foreign key relationship.
- For every row in `written_by` you add a relationship between the `Author` node and `Book` node referenced

For queries in neo4j I recommend [cypher](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/cypher-query-lang.html) due to its expressiveness. A (2.0) query looking for books by some author would look like:

```
MATCH (author:Author)-[:written_by]-(book:Book)
WHERE author.name='Hugh Laurie'
RETURN book.title
```

Answer (score 2):

You actually have several options at hand:

- use the [Talend connector for Neo4J](https://github.com/Zenika/talend-neo4j-connector)
- export your schema+data in CSV files consumable by the [batch importer](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import)
- or you can do it [programmatically](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/batchinsert.html)

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

The musicbrainz -> neo4j
https://github.com/redapple/sql2graph/tree/master/examples/musicbrainz

Neo4j Sql-importer
https://github.com/peterneubauer/sql-import

Good Luck!